# Drag and drop objects simultaneously

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I face a problem... and am looking for a solution or an idea. I want to drag drop several objects (markers,polylines,...) simultaneously, but I do not know if this is possible ...

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks in advance !
Regards,
Sebastien

---

Thanks Nils !!!
You give me the good way !
Here you have how i've made it possible :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(window["Overlay" + i] , 'click', function(event) {
var path = this.getPath();
google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'set_at', function(indEdited,newLatLng){
        var oo = this.getAt(indEdited);
        diffLat = (newLatLng.lat() - oo.lat());
        diffLng = (newLatLng.lng() - oo.lng());
        moveOverlay(this,indEdited,diffLat,diffLng);
       var temp = "Do you want to me the others overlays ?"
        if (fromPath == lastPath )
        {
            if ( confirm(temp) ){
                moveOthersOverlays(diffLat,diffLng);
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it's only markers that you can drag n' drop, so you must design the functionality with this in mind.

First we need to now the starting position, this is done with the dragstart event. Please not that you have to do this on all your markers.

```
var startLatLng;
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(){
  marker.getPosition()
});
```

You will utilize the function the drag event, and loop over all objects. I will utilize pseudo code here, let me know if it's something that is unclear. The assumption is that you save your markers in an array

```
google.maps.event.addListener(dragmarker, 'drag', function(){
   end = dragmarker.getPosition();
   for (marker in markers){
      // Don't care about marker being dragged
      if (dragmarker == marker)
          continue;
      current = marker.getPossition();
      // Bellow we create a new position for the marker by calculating the difference 
      // and add it to the current possition of the marker
      marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(
                    current.lat() + (end.lat() - start.lat()), 
                    current.lng() + (end.lng() + start.lng()));
   }

   // Same same for the polylines but you will have to loop over the path
});
```

Please note that this will be really slow if there are alot of objects that you are moving around. But this works great for me when moving a couple of markers and a small polyline. Also, please note that the code is a bit crude, I just wanted to show how it's done. In my solution I'm storing my markers and polylines in objects that will update them self.

You can check out my code at [this github repo](https://github.com/otm/otm/blob/master/app/libraries/js/otm/class.gate.js)